# Magento URL rewrite and SEO

Tags: magento, url, url-rewriting

The website is in a sub-folder:

```
www.example.com/sub-folder/index.php/webpage.html
```

How do I hide `/sub-folder/index.php/` to make the displayed URL `www.example.com/webpage.html`? Does hiding it affect SEO at all?

Comment: Is your website running on Apache? .htaccess rewrites could do the trick then.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is ideal to be without /sub-folder/, but it would not matter that much if you have it under the subfolder directory as long as you take care of the other onpage factors on your shop. 
Why don't you move the website to the root directory?

Answer (score 0):

If the magento installed under /shop or directory then add the following rules into ” /home/username/public_html/shop/.htaccess ” file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /shop/index.php [L]</IfModule>
```

check this link http://roshanlal.in/magento/how-to-remove-index-php-in-url-with-magento/

hope this will help you